# I keep getting an error in my android project

Tags: android

I keep getting an error the values-v11 folder on the style.xml The error says:

> error: Error Retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

I'm using Android SDK 2.3

Comment: What do you have your target SDK set to?

Answer (score 0):

With android sdk 2.3 you can not control or change behavior of action bar..
for that min sdk should be sdk 3.0 or above.
for further you can see this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).